# Use hard code in MVC3 Razor view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following Razor code:

```
<td>
    <div class="editor-label">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountCode)
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="editor-field">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AccountCode)            
    </div>
</td>
```

I would like to hard code the value `1001` as a default for the Input field. I have tried  `[model.accountcode ="1001"]` which does not work.

Please explain with example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set a value in the model, that should be done in the controller...

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var myModel = new ModelClass();
    myModel.AccountCode = 1001;
    return View("MyViewName", myModel);
}
```

Then use the normal syntax in Razor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountCode)
```

Or if you just want a hidden parameter:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AccountCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display some value directly in the textbox then you should try

```
@Html.TextBox("AccountCode", "1001")
```

Comment: Actually i want don't display control in my browse but i want to save "accountCode = 1001"